# How can I prove this equality?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

I'm not sure how I can prove this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Let\; x\in (V+W)^\perp \Rightarrow (x,v+w)=0$ where $v\in V \; and\; w\in W$

$(x,v+w)=0 $

$\Rightarrow (x,v)+(x,w)=0$

$\Rightarrow (x,v)=0\;and\;(x,w)=0$

$\Rightarrow x\in V^\perp\;and\;x\in W^\perp$

$\Rightarrow x\in V^\perp \cap W^\perp$

and all these steps holds backwards too.

This solves your problem.

Comment: Your jump from line three to line four is unjustified as it is: from $\;a+b=0\;$ it does not, in general, follow that $\;a=0\,,\,b=0\;$ . You have to do cases (or, perhaps, otherwise).

Comment: Because third line is true for all $v\in V$ and for all $w \in W$, taking $v$ and $w$ to be zero vector one by one leaad to fourth line.

Comment: I know yet you should have written, in my opinion,  that in your answer. But it doesn't matter now as the asker already accepted your answer as it is.

Comment: I just gave the outline, assuming that asker should fill the details itself. And if he/she has doubt , they can comment it.